# Improve accuracy Naive Bayes Classifier

Tags: python, classification, nltk, naivebayes

I wrote a simple document classifier and I am currently testing it on the Brown Corpus. However, my accuracy is still very low (0.16). I've already excluded stopwords. Any other ideas on how to improve the classifier's performance?

```
import nltk, random

from nltk.corpus import brown, stopwords



documents = [(list(brown.words(fileid)), category)
        for category in brown.categories()
        for fileid in brown.fileids(category)]


random.shuffle(documents)

stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))


all_words = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in brown.words() if w in stop) 

word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]

def document_features(document):
    document_words = set(document)
    features = {}
    for word in word_features:
       features['contains(%s)' % word] = (word in document_words)
    return features

featuresets = [(document_features(d), c) for (d,c) in documents] 

train_set, test_set = featuresets[100:], featuresets[:100]

classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

print(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set))
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with the code edition, there seem to be two lines that are commented before classifier = nltk... that are required. BTW, this does not use a naive bayes classifier, but a Decision Tree Classifier so you should probably change the tag and title.

Comment: You're not excluding stop words, you're only including them.

Change:

`all_words = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower for w in brown.words() if w in stop)`

to 

`all_words = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower for w in brown.words() if w not in stop)`

Answer (score 2):

If that's really your code, it's a wonder you get anything at all. `w.lower` is not a string, it's a function (method) object. You need to add the parentheses:

```
>>> w = "The"
>>> w.lower
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x10231e8b8>
>>> w.lower()
'the'
```

(But who knows really. You need to fix the code in your question, it's full of cut-and-paste errors and who knows what else. Next time, help us help you better.)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by changing the first comment from:

import corpus documents = [(list(brown.words(fileid)), category) to:

documents = [(list(brown.words(fileid)), category) ...

In addition to changing the w.lower as the other answer says.

Changing this and following these two links below which implements a basic Naive Classifier without removing stop words gave me an accuracy of 33% which is a lot higher than 16%. 
https://pythonprogramming.net/words-as-features-nltk-tutorial/
https://pythonprogramming.net/naive-bayes-classifier-nltk-tutorial/?completed=/words-as-features-nltk-tutorial/

There are lots of things you can try to see if it improves your accuracy:

1- removing stop words

2- removing punctuation

3- removing the most common words and the least common words

4- normalizing the text

5- stemming or lemmatizing the text

6- I think this feature-set gives True if the word is present and False if it is not present. You can implement a count or a frequency.

7- You can use unigrams, bigrams and trigrams or combinations of those.

Hope that helped

Comment: Thanks, I'm a total Python beginner and I really appreciate your help